# Filter on diff in R data.table

Tags: r, filter, data.table

I would like to filter on the result of the diff() function and use the efficiency of data.table.

```
DT[diff(timestamp) > 10]
```

won't do the work as the resultset is shorter than the source. Even creating a filter and than subsetting creates at least a warn (which I would like to prevent).

```
DT[, filter := diff(timestamp) > 10]
```

I could use dplyr or else, but I would like the efficency of data.table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you have to append or prepend a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value depending on what you want to achieve. That is not data.table specific but follows from the simple fact that a differences is always between two values.

Comment: @Roland, yes, that is clear. My question was about what is programatically the cleanest way to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stems from the nature of `diff()`, as Roland pointed out . It returns a vector of length `n-1` when applied to a vector of length `n`.

Example:

```
diff(c(2, 4, 9))
[1] 2 5
```

When subsetting data.table with a logical vector its number of rows have to be equal to the vector's length. So possible solutions would include:

```
DT[-1][diff(DT$timestamp) > 10]
DT[c(FALSE, diff(timestamp) > 10)]
```

I would probably do something like this:

```
DT[timestamp - shift(timestamp) > 10]
```